# TensorFlow - Input 'split_dim' of 'Split' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of int32

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've installed tensorflow using pip on ubuntu 16.04 LTS, when running this code https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py i am getting this error

```
Successfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes. 
Extracting /tmp/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 
Successfully downloaded train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 28881 bytes. Extracting /tmp/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 
Successfully downloaded t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 1648877 bytes. 
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 4542 bytes. 
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "deep.py", line 71, in <module>
        pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)   
    File "deep.py", line 60, in RNN
        x = tf.split(x, n_steps, 0)   
    File "/home/newuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1234, in split
        name=name)   
    File "/home/newuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3241, in _split
    num_split=num_split, name=name)   
    File "/home/newuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 508, in apply_op
    (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name)) 
TypeError: Input 'split_dim' of 'Split' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of int32.
```

Answer (score 36):

It looks like you are using an older version of Tensorflow, and need to update to Tensorflow v0.12.0 or above. The error you are getting is indicating that the `split_dim` value in your `tf.split` function is expecting an integer, but is receiving the tensor `x` which is of type float32.

This is because in Tensorflow versions < 0.12.0 the split function takes the arguments as:

```
x = tf.split(0, n_steps, x) # tf.split(axis, num_or_size_splits, value)
```

The tutorial you are working from was written for versions > 0.12.0, which has been changed to be consistent with Numpy's split syntax:

```
x = tf.split(x, n_steps, 0) # tf.split(value, num_or_size_splits, axis)
```

See the changelog for details: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/64edd34ce69b4a8033af5d217cb8894105297d8a/RELEASE.md

Comment: Hi alphaleonis, I am using Tensorflow 0.12.0-rc0, but it still has this kind of error message.

Comment: Yes, Tensorflow 0.12.0-rc0 and 0.12.0-rc1 are pre-release versions that still contain the old syntax. The new syntax change didn't take effect until v0.12.0. You can see when the change was committed to the official repository here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/a46b6d211eac423c72d3a57a177daf2f64db8642#diff-68052049ee5dc7573829a5fdb7a57310

Answer (score 9):

It is because the argument order has changed

You can see the issue here : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6501

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In other words, what is the solution?

Comment: You can look at this link (which, is referred in the above link): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/64edd34ce69b4a8033af5d217cb8894105297d8a/RELEASE.md. 

All you need to do is to write the arguments in a different order. like that: tf.split(value, num_or_size_splits, axis)