# the error message of TypeError: Input 'split_dim' of 'Split' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of int32

Tags: tensorflow

Running a `tensorflow` model generates the following error message. Googling it seems to be caused by the [tensorflow version being < 0.12.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842440/tensorflow-input-split-dim-of-split-op-has-type-float32-that-does-not-matc).  The version of tensorflow I am using is `0.12.0-rc0`.

```
 File "/home/ug/GPU-Study/keras/FCN/fcn/tensorflow_fcn/fcn8_vgg.py", line 60, in build
red, green, blue = tf.split(rgb, 3, 3)
 File "/devl/tensorflow/tf_0.12/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1159, in split
name=name)
 File "/devl/tensorflow/tf_0.12/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3241, in _split
num_split=num_split, name=name)
 File "/devl/tensorflow/tf_0.12/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 508, in apply_op
(prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name))
 TypeError: Input 'split_dim' of 'Split' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of int32.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your [linked SO post above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842440/tensorflow-input-split-dim-of-split-op-has-type-float32-that-does-not-matc), @alphaleonis points out that Tensorflow 0.12.0-rc0 and 0.12.0-rc1 are pre-release versions that still contain the old syntax. The new syntax change didn't take effect until v0.12.0.

So update ot v0.12 or better v1.0.0. Good luck!

**Update**:
If you cannot update the underlying libraries, then you should use the previous/older/pre-v0.12 signature for `tf.split`:

```
# tf.split(axis, num_or_size_splits, value)
```

In your case use:
   `red, green, blue = tf.split(3, 3, rgb)`

Comment: Hi ruoho, thanks for the advice. Since I have quite some code base relying on old version. Is that possible to make any modification on the program itself to make it run on the olde version like 0.12.0-rc0.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the response to show (based on the error being from `tf.split(rgb,3,3)`, how you use the older form of `tf.split`. See if that works!