# Tensorflow TypeError: Input 'pred' of 'Switch' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of bool

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science

I'm currently working on building a deep neural network using Tensorflow, and encountering some issues implementing a regularization technique called dropout (check out the original paper by Geoffrey Hinton [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0580.pdf)).

Tensorflow has a function to take care of this, and I'm following a tutorial by Aurelien Geron's book *Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & Tensorflow* (which, by the way, is incredible). In it, his sample code to implement dropout consists of declaring a `training` placeholder:

```
training = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (), name = "training")
```

and then creating the hidden layer dropout object:

```
hidden1_drop = tf.layers.dropout(hidden1, dropout_rate, training = training)
```

However, when I execute this, I receive an error pointing to the above line.

```
TypeError: Input 'pred' of 'Switch' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of bool
```

I looked into the [Tensorflow documentation regarding dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout), `tf.layers.dropout()` method's `training` parameter is defined as

> Either a Python boolean, or a TensorFlow boolean scalar tensor (e.g. a
>   placeholder). Whether to return the output in training mode (apply
>   dropout) or in inference mode (return the input untouched).

However, in the code above, I'm clearly passing in `tf.float32`. I suspect this is the cause of my error- it's even stated in the error message itself. So was this simply a typo by the author, or am I not understanding what is happening behind the scenes?

Should I just replace the hidden layer declaration with this line instead?

```
hidden1_drop = tf.layers.dropout(hidden1, dropout_rate, training = True)
```

I've also looked into other SO [posts with similar errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842440/tensorflow-input-split-dim-of-split-op-has-type-float32-that-does-not-matc), like this one, but the answers seem to suggest that the error stems from an outdated version of Tensorflow, which is not the case- I only recently installed on my machine a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question since I'm an idiot.

The author did not make a typo. I made a typo following his tutorial. `training` can be either a Python boolean or a Tensorflow boolean tensor. In the book, the author's actual code was

```
training = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=())
```

Making this switch should solve the issue.