# TensorFlow version 1.3.0 - Input 'split_dim' of 'Split' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of int32

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running the code from [github](https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/LSTM-Human-Activity-Recognition), and encountered the error in the following lines:

```
 # Split the series because the rnn cell needs time_steps features, each of shape:
 hidden = tf.split(0, config.n_steps, feature_mat)
 print (len(hidden), str(hidden[0].get_shape()))
 # New shape: a list of lenght "time_step" containing tensors of shape [batch_size, n_hidden]
```

The error message is:

> TypeError: Input 'split_dim' of 'Split' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of int32.

I have saw similar questions on StackOverflow, and the issue resulted from outdated version of tensorflow, but my version of tensorflow is 1.3.

Comment: Have you tried swapping `feature_mat` and `0` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41868500/5200287) answer suggests?

Comment: Yes this is very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is because that you are using an older version of **tf.split**. Modify your code as follows and should be working.

```
hidden = tf.split(feature_mat, config.n_steps, 0)
```

Hope this helps.